# How can I display code lenses at the end of the line in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to show references count at the end of the line in Visual Studio Code. How can I do it?

[image: image of reference counts showing above the property line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this right now. It's not supported. But there is an open issue discussing it: [Explore line-end-rendering of code lenses #90235](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90235). Here's what you can do:

- Give the issue ticket a thumbs up reaction to show support.
- Subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress.
- Avoid making noisy comments like "+1". If you want to contribute to discussion, do so in a way that is meaningful and contributes toward forward progress.

You can also find some historical discussion on the subject in this issue ticket, which can be helpful to read up on if you want to contribute to discussion: [Feature Request: change CodeLens position in the editor to make loading smoother #23652](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23652). Ex. Part of the challenge on the engineering side of things is how long it might take to calculate sizes for the codelens for line rendering purposes.

For your reference / learning purposes, the above issue tickets can be found by googling "`github vscode issues show codelens at end of line`".